# Search for 2 different patterns on 2 different lines and print them in a single line?

Tags: grep

I have a file like this (1), and I want to an output like that (2). With "grep -e file -e index" I got this (3). Do you know what is missing to achieve the structure in (2)?

(1)

```
file: path/to/file1
other info_1
index = a
file: path/to/file2
other info_2
index = b
file: path/to/file3
other info_3
index = c
...
```

(2)

```
file: path/to/file1 index = a
file: path/to/file2 index = b
file: path/to/file3 index = c
...
```

(3)

```
file: path/to/file1 
index = a
file: path/to/file2 
index = b
file: path/to/file3 
index = c
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is always every other line, `paste` will do:

```
grep -e file -e index infile | paste - -
```